# SimpleInjector - Register a type for all it's interfaces

Tags: dependency-injection, simple-injector

Is it possible to register a type for all it's implementing interfaces?  E.g, I have a:

```
public class Bow : IWeapon
{

    #region IWeapon Members

    public string Attack()
    {
        return "Shooted with a bow";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class HumanFighter 

{
    private readonly IWeapon weapon = null;
    public HumanFighter(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public string Fight()
    {

        return this.weapon.Attack();
    }

}

    [Test]
    public void Test2b()
    {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.RegisterSingle<Bow>();
        container.RegisterSingle<HumanFighter>();

        // this would match the IWeapon to the Bow, as it
        // is implemented by Bow
        var humanFighter1 = container.GetInstance<HumanFighter>(); 

        string s = humanFighter1.Fight();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on your needs, but typically you need to use the `Container`'s non-generic registration method. You can define your own LINQ queries to query the application's metadata to get the proper types, and register them using the non-generic registration methods. Here's an example:

```cs
var weaponsAssembly = typeof(Bow).Assembly;

var registrations =
    from type in weaponsAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where type.Namespace.Contains(".Weapons")
    from service in type.GetInterfaces()
    select new { Service = service, Implementation = type };

foreach (var reg in registrations)
{
    container.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation);
}
```

If you need to batch-register a set of implementations, based on a shared generic interface, you can use the [RegisterManyForOpenGeneric](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Registration-Of-Open-Generic-Types) extension method:

```cs
// include the SimpleInjector.Extensions namespace.

container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>),
    typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly);
```

This will look for all (non-generic) public types in the supplied assembly that implement `IValidator<T>` and registers each of them by their closed-generic implementation. If an type implements multiple closed-generic versions of `IValidator<T>`, all versions will be registered. Take a look at the following example:

```cs
interface IValidator<T> { }
class MultiVal1 : IValidator<Customer>, IValidator<Order> { }
class MultiVal2 : IValidator<User>, IValidator<Employee> { }

container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>),
    typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly);
```

Assuming the given interface and class definitions, the shown `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` registration is equivalent to the following manual registration:

```cs
container.Register<IValidator<Customer>, MultiVal1>();
container.Register<IValidator<Order>, MultiVal1>();
container.Register<IValidator<User>, MultiVal2>();
container.Register<IValidator<Employee>, MultiVal2>();
```

It would also be easy to add convenient extension methods. Take for instance the following extension method that allows you to register a single implementation by all its implemented interfaces:

```cs
public static void RegisterAsImplementedInterfaces<TImpl>(
    this Container container)
{
    foreach (var service in typeof(TImpl).GetInterfaces())
    {
        container.Register(service, typeof(TImpl));
    }
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterAsImplementedInterfaces<Sword>();
```

Comment: I would like to do automatic-wiring for the components used - I can do it via reflection, but is there anything that can automatically register a type and automatically wire it for all its implementing interfaces?

Comment: Batch registration is supported out-of-the-box for generic types, but not for non-generic interfaces. This is a deliberate design decision. You can more about that [here](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Batch_Registration). It will tell you why it isn't supported, and how to do this by using reflection. If you've got any problems with this, please let me know. I'll be happy to assist you.

Comment: I've solved it via reflection - However i wanted to know if it was possible to be done natively, like you could do with some other Ioc Containers.  Then again, it's not a big issue and can be easily implemented via reflection.

Comment: Instead of having to learn a total new API (and every DI container has it's own rather awkward API for this), I desired to provide just the minimal API that allows you to use LINQ queries + reflection (a language and API you already know) to do this. This also translates easily to other frameworks, since a rewrite to a different DI container would be trivial. Some developers like to use complex tools; I don't. I like to keep things simple :-)